# Logic: Applying gravity to a vector

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

There is a method called `gravity(Vector[] vector)` The vector contains sequence of numbers. The gravity function should return a new vector after applying gravity which is explained below.

Assume 0's are air and 1's are brick. When gravity is applied the bricks should fall down to the lowest level.

Let vector = [3, 7, 8]

Converting this to binary we get:
0 0 1 1 for 3
0 1 1 1 for 7
1 0 0 0 for 8

Applying gravity:
0 0 0 0 which is 0
0 0 1 1 which is 3
1 1 1 1 which is 15

So the gravity function should return [0, 3, 15].

Hope you people understood the explanation. I tried a lot but I couldn't figure out the logic for this. One thing I observed was the sum of the numbers in the vector before and after applying gravity remains same.

That is,
3 + 7 + 8 = 18 = 0 + 3 + 15 for the above case.

Comment: Will the vectors always have 3 elements, or are you looking for a general solution?

Comment: General solution actually.

Comment: What is your question exactly? do want an algorithm for the gravity function? or do you want to know why the sum stays the same?

Comment: I need an algorithm for the gravity function.

Comment: Please see my answer below. I think it is easy to understand, simple to code, and has very good performance as well (should be able to run in 1 second for vector size N <= 10^9)  :)

Comment: All the answers seem to be correct. So I didn't choose a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is as simple as counting the total '1' bit of each position...

Let **N** be the input vector size, **b** be the longest binary length of the input elements

1. Pre-compute the total # of '1' bit of each position, stored in count[], O(N*b)
2. Run Gravity Function, that is, to regenerate N numbers from the count[], O(N*b)

Total run time is O(N*b)

Below is the sample code in C++

```html
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int v[5] = {3,9,7,8,5};
int cnt[5] = {0};
vector<int> ans;

vector<int> gravity(){
 vector<int> ret;
 for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
  int s = 0;
  for(int j=0; j<5;j++)
   if(cnt[j]){
    s += (1<<j); cnt[j]--;
   }
  ret.push_back(s);
 }
 return ret;
}

int main(){
 
 // precompute sum of 1 of each bit
 for(int i=0, j=0, tmp=v[i]; i<5; i++, j=0, tmp=v[i]){
  while(tmp){
   if(tmp&1) cnt[j]++;
   tmp >>= 1; j++;
  }
 }
 
 ans = gravity();
 
 for(int i=ans.size()-1; i>=0; i--) printf("%d ", ans[i]);
 
 return 0; 
}
```

The output is as follows:

> Success   time: 0 memory: 3272 signal:0
>
> 0 1 1 15 15

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of so far uses nested `for` loops:

- `v` is the input vector of `N` integers
- `D` is the number of digits in each integer
- `c` keeps track of the bottom-most free space where a brick can fall

The algorithm checks if the `i`th bit in the number `n` is set using `(n & (1<<i))`, which works in most C-like languages.

The algorithm in C:

```
for (int j=0; j<D; ++j)
    int bit = 1<<j;
    int c = N-1;
    for (int i=N-1; i>=0; --i)
        if (v[i] & bit) {   // if bit j of number v[i] is set...
            v[i] ^= bit;    // set bit j in the number i to 0 using XOR
            v[c] ^= bit; // set bottom-most bit in the number i to 1 using XOR
            c -= 1;       //increment by bottom row 1 
        }
```

---

If `N` is small and known it advance, you could work out the truth tables for the values of each digit and get the correct result using only bitwise operations and no loops.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what is r. Can you explain? And I was told that it can be solved in 5 minutes. So I think the logic wouldn't be so complex.

Comment: `r[j]` keeps track of how high we've "built up" `1`'s relative to the ground in the `j`th digit/column. When you say "solved in 5 minutes", do you mean in terms of program runtime, or the amount of time it takes to think of a solution. This might merit some more thought for a better answer.

Comment: By "solved in 5 minutes" I mean the amount of time it takes to think of a solution.

Comment: Evidently I'm not that smart. :) I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: Edited my answer to make it simpler. Reversing the order of the loops makes it slightly faster as well.

Comment: @shole I think it's very similar to what you did. The only difference is that you count the ones and then make them fall, whereas I try to make them fall one-by-one without counting them. They both end up being `O(n*D)`/`O(n*b)` algorithms.

Comment: @eigenchris what I meant is that basically all answers here are based on "simulation" while mine is simply counting (intuitive to me as well...) Actually I did not go deep in other's answer, but what I was thinking is that "counting can never be more complicated than simulating a gravity effect"...of course the complexity maybe the same, but it's the way of thinking matters (As title, "Logic")

Comment: @shole I see. Yes, I'd agree yours is simpler to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Start at the bottom.  Any bricks in the row on top of that one will fall down except where there is already a brick on the bottom. So, the new bottom row is:

bottom_new = bottom_old OR top_old

The new top is:

top_new = bottom_old AND top_old

That is, there will be a brick in the new bottom row if there was a brick in either row, but there's only going to be a brick in the new top row if there was a brick in both rows.

Then you just work your way up the stack, with the new top row becoming the old bottom row for the next step.

Comment: I was thinking of this approach too, but you will need to repeat this process multiple times, as bricks will not fall more than one row if you only do this process once. (Imagine only a single brick in the top row, for example--it will only move one row down.) In the worst case you will need to repeat the process `N` times for `N` rows with two nested loops. But given how fast `AND` and `OR` operations are, it's not a bad idea and possibly faster than the solution I posted.

Comment: I read the question as being about calculating the result for a single step.  I can't think of a better way to calculate the final result than what you or shole posted

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

So I found a solution which needs recursion I guess. Though I don't know the condition to stop the recursion.

The vector v = [3, 7, 8] is very simple that its not possible to explain why recursion is required so am considering a new vector v = [3, 9, 7, 8, 5]

**In binary form :**

```
0 0 1 1 - a4  
1 0 0 1 - a3  
0 1 1 1 - a2  
1 0 0 0 - a1  
0 1 0 1 - a0
```

**Iteration 1 :**

```
0 0 0 0 - b7  (b7 = a4 AND b5)  
0 0 1 1 - b6  (b6 = a4 OR b5)  
0 0 0 0 - b5  (b5 = a3 AND b3) ignore this  
1 0 0 1 - b4  (b4 = a3 OR b3)
0 0 0 0 - b3  (b3 = a2 AND b1) ignore this  
0 1 1 1 - b2  (b2 = a2 OR b1)  
0 0 0 0 - b1  (b1 = a0 AND a1) ignore this    
1 1 0 1 - b0  (b0 = a0 OR a1)  
  
Intermediate vector = [b7, b6, b4, b2, b0] = [0, 3, 9, 7, 13]
```

**Iteration 2 :**

```
0 0 0 0 - c7  (c7 = b4 AND c5)  
0 0 0 1 - c6  (c6 = b4 OR c5)  
0 0 0 1 - c5  (c5 = b3 AND c3) ignore this  
0 0 1 1 - c4  (c4 = b3 OR c3)  
0 0 0 1 - c3  (c3 = b2 AND c1) ignore this   
1 1 0 1 - c2  (c2 = b2 OR c1)  
0 1 0 1 - c1  (c1 = b0 AND b1) ignore this   
1 1 1 1 - c0  (c0 = b0 OR b1)  
  
Intermediate vector = [c7, c6, c4, c2, c0] = [0, 1, 3, 13, 15]
```

**Iteration 3 :**

```
0 0 0 0 - d7 (d7 = c4 AND d5)  
0 0 0 1 - d6 (d6 = c4 OR d5)  
0 0 0 1 - d5 (d5 = c3 AND d3) ignore this  
0 0 0 1 - d4 (d4 = c3 OR d3)  
0 0 0 1 - d3 (d3 = c2 AND d1) ignore this      
1 1 1 1 - d2 (d2 = c2 OR d1)  
1 1 0 1 - d1 (d1 = c0 AND c1) ignore this 
1 1 1 1 - d0 (d0 = c0 OR c1)  
  
Resultant vector = [d7, d6, d4, d2, d0] = [0, 1, 1, 15, 15]
```

I got this solution by going backwards through the vector.

## Another solution:

1. Construct a multidimensional array with all the bits of all the elements in the vector (i.e) if v = [3,7,8] then construct a 3x4 array and store all the bits.
2. Count the number of 1's in each column and store the count.
3. Fill each column with count number of 1's starting from the bottom bit.

This approach is simple but requires construction of large matrices.

Comment: I think your first solution is pretty good. Checking for a stopping condition might actually turn out to be worse than simply doing `N` iterations for `N` rows (which would guarantee all the bricks have fallen into place). All together that would be `2*N*(N-1)` bitwise operations, which is likely faster than mine. I was trying to get the bricks to fall immediately into place, but I pay for it by having to do a lot more operations.